# How to change the format of moment.js in an angular 2 project

Tags: angular, angular-material, momentjs

I have used

```
public now = moment().format();
```

to display the current date in an html form. It displays `"1/17/2018"` but I also wanted to display the time along with the date. I tried using

```
public now = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
```

but it didnt work. Did I do something wrong?

This is how i implemented it on html:

```js
this.sdate = this.now;

this.addvisitorForm = this.fb.group(({
  check_in: [  this.sdate],
}));
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-sm-12 lfield">
    <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="check_in" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="check_in"
        placeholder="Check In Date/Time :" required>     
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Marked in bold, those characters are invalid formatting characters

public now = moment().format('MM**MM** Do YYYY, h:mm:ss **a**');

Try

public now = moment().format('MM DD YYYY, h:mm:ss');

Comment: No it didnt work. itried other formats too but it doesnt work.

Comment: Please check the following link to know more about parsing https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/

Comment: Please note that both `MMMM` and `a` are **valid** format tokens, `MMMM` stands for month name and `a` stands for `am/pm`, see [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) docs.